# YouTube Analytics report query suddenly failing (worked before)

Tags: youtube-api

The following YouTube Analytics query is suddenly failing for me (has worked for the past couple of weeks):

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==[my channel id]&start-date=2010-10-27&end-date=2010-10-30&metrics=views&dimensions=day,insightTrafficSourceType&sort=day&prettyPrint=false

The error:

{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"badRequest","message":"Invalid query. Query did not conform to the expectations."}],"code":400,"message":"Invalid query. Query did not conform to the expectations."}}

Appears to be related to the "insightTrafficSourceType" dimension as the query succeeds if I only use the "day" dimension.  This also fails if I use the "insightPlaybackLocationType" dimensions.

Did something change with the API?  I would like to use both of these dimensions in my reports.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is not a good place to report bugs; I've opened a public issue tracker bug report for this problem at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3963, and I'd recommend "Star"ing that to keep updated on the status of the issue.

Also see http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html for info on creating bug reports/feature requests yourself.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for opening the bug report for me.  Hopefully it gets resolved soon.